# Is D&D Beyond correct in showing my ranger's attack bonus being higher than his Dex mod + bonus from Archery Fighting Style?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, attack-roll, fighting-style, dnd-beyond

In a campaign I am joining, I am playing an Owlin Ranger. Since we're starting at level 3, my subclass is Gloom Stalker.

Every time I create this character, D&D Beyond keeps saying I have an attack bonus of +9 for my bow. Shouldn't it just be +7?

- Dexterity score is 20, which gives a +5 bonus
- Fighting Style: Archery gives a +2 bonus

So I'm a bit lost on why I'm getting the extra +2.

Comment: @V2Blast : I'd suggest dropping this from hot network questions; I don't think it's generally interesting, just a simple oversight of a well-known part of the 5e system, and it's already correctly answered.  I was certainly hoping for something more obscure and thus interesting to me when I clicked the original title.  Our edits might help some, in avoiding people wasting their time, but people still have to read through the long title and spot the missing piece (i.e. answer it themselves) to realize it's not interesting to them.

Comment: (Dan: that doesn't mean it's a "bad" question.  Just that you don't need the continued attention of everyone on this simple question that's already answered.)

Answer (score 36):

#### Proficiency bonus.

As a ranger you have proficiency with your bow, so your +2 proficiency bonus is added to your bonus to hit. The rule for “Modifiers to the Roll” in the Attack Rolls section of the combat rules states:

> ***Proficiency Bonus.*** You add your proficiency bonus to your attack roll when you attack using a weapon with which you have proficiency, as well as when you attack with a spell.

So +9 is correct: +5 (dexterity) + 2 (proficiency) + 2 (Archery fighting style) = +9 to hit.

Comment: I completely forgot prof XD Thankyou! It's been a few years.

Comment: @Dantheman007 Sure thing, it happens to all of us.

Comment: @Dantheman007 If the answer resolves your question (which based on its correctness and your comment, seems to be the case), you can click the checkmark to accept it.